# XafariMultipleLookupPropertyEditor Cannot convert XPCollection to XPCollection'1

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have  `XPCollection<MyClass>` as property of persistent class.
I try to use `XafariMultipleLookupPropertyEditor` as Editor in DetailView.
When I select item I get error **The value XPCollection(1574) Count(1) can not be cast to type XPCollection'1**

Can anybody help?